# Reshape excel table with stacked date column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I have an excel file that has diffrent weather stations and the minimum and maximum temprature of every month in a year like this:

| Name | Time | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Station 1 | 2020-01 | -10 | 2 |
|  | ... | ... | ... |
|  | 2020-12 | -5 | 0 |
| Station 2 | 2020-01 | -8 | 4 |
|  | ... | ... | ... |
|  | 2020-12 | -6 | 4 |
| Station 3 | 2020-01 | -8 | 5 |
|  | ... | ... | ... |
|  | 2020-12 | -5 | 5 |
| Station 4 | 2020-01 | -9 | 5 |
|  | ... | ... | ... |
|  | 2020-12 | -11 | 4 |

Not quite well versed in Python, but have been trying to follow the pandas user guide and looking at forums using different methods to pivot the table with pandas so the header with the values below becomes like this, but without luck.

| Date | Minimum - Station 1 | Maximum - Station 1 | ... | Minimum - Station 4 | Maximum - Station 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

This was my final attempt. It results into outputing the header in the wrong order, and the first row of values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')

result = df.pivot_table(index='Time', columns='Name', values=['Minimum', 'Maximum'])

result.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in result.columns]

result.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pivot makes sense to me too. Is that where your problems is occurring? Then maybe some of the columns in your example data are part of the index of your input table. The most difficult part is to get all the columns sorted and named as in your expected output. This works for me with some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": np.repeat([f"Station {i}" for i in range(1, 5)], 12),
    "Time": np.tile([f"2020-{i:02d}" for i in range(1, 13)], 4),
    "Minimum": np.random.randint(-10, 0, size=48),
    "Maximum": np.random.randint(0, 10, size=48)
})

df = df.pivot(index="Time", columns="Name")
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=[1, 0], ascending=[True, False])
df = df.set_axis(df.columns.to_flat_index().map(" - ".join), axis=1)
df = df.reset_index(names="Date")
```

output:

```
       Date  Minimum - Station 1  Maximum - Station 1  ...  Maximum - Station 3  Minimum - Station 4  Maximum - Station 4
0   2020-01                   -9                    2  ...                    1                   -4                    5
1   2020-02                   -4                    5  ...                    2                   -9                    5
2   2020-03                   -1                    8  ...                    2                   -7                    0
3   2020-04                   -9                    0  ...                    9                   -7                    7
4   2020-05                   -4                    6  ...                    1                   -4                    9
5   2020-06                   -9                    2  ...                    6                   -2                    5
6   2020-07                   -9                    2  ...                    1                   -5                    5
7   2020-08                   -6                    2  ...                    8                   -6                    0
8   2020-09                   -3                    2  ...                    2                  -10                    0
9   2020-10                   -2                    5  ...                    1                   -2                    4
10  2020-11                  -10                    7  ...                    7                   -2                    5
11  2020-12                   -6                    8  ...                    3                   -2                    8
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to specify the problem, edited it in. 

Station names was only listed besides the first month of the year with NaN values between. Resolved it by using df['Name'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True). 

Also df = df.reset_index(names="Date") didn't work, got TypeError: DataFrame.reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names' resolved it by using df = df.rename_axis("Date", axis='index'). 

Then your solution worked great! However, not that it really matters. The first station ended up being listed last in the pivoted table, any idea why?